# AWS limit subnet query to a single subnet ID

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to automate the creation of VPC endpoints throughout my organization and I need to attach at least one subnet (AZ doesn't matter), but I'm having some difficulty filtering the subnets to a single ID. Here is what I have so far:

```
import boto3
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
    vpc = ec2.describe_vpcs()
    subnet = ec2.describe_subnets(
        Filters=[
            {
                'Name': 'availabilityZone',
                'Values':[
                    'us-east-1a',
                ],
                'Name': 'defaultForAz',
                'Values': [
                    'true',
                ]
            },
        ],
    )
    subs = subnet['Subnets']
    vpcs = vpc['Vpcs']

    for v in vpcs:
        ec2.create_vpc_endpoint(
            #DryRun=True,
            VpcEndpointType='Interface',
            VpcId=f"{v['VpcId']}",
            SubnetIds=[
                f"{subs['SubnetId']}",
            ],
            ServiceName='com.amazonaws.us-east-1.ssm',
            PrivateDnsEnabled=False
        )
```

The error I'm getting is that `list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

I am unsure how to remedy this considering the AWS boto3 documentation is requesting that the SubnetId value is a 'string':

**COPIED FROM AWS DOCUMENTATION**:

```
response = client.create_vpc_endpoint(
    DryRun=True|False,
    VpcEndpointType='Interface'|'Gateway'|'GatewayLoadBalancer',
    VpcId='string',
    ServiceName='string',
    PolicyDocument='string',
    RouteTableIds=[
        'string',
    ],
    SubnetIds=[
        'string',
    ],
    SecurityGroupIds=[
        'string',
    ],
    IpAddressType='ipv4'|'dualstack'|'ipv6',
    DnsOptions={
        'DnsRecordIpType': 'ipv4'|'dualstack'|'ipv6'|'service-defined'
    },
    ClientToken='string',
    PrivateDnsEnabled=True|False,
    TagSpecifications=[
        {
            'ResourceType': 'capacity-reservation'|'client-vpn-endpoint'|'customer-gateway'|'carrier-gateway'|'dedicated-host'|'dhcp-options'|'egress-only-internet-gateway'|'elastic-ip'|'elastic-gpu'|'export-image-task'|'export-instance-task'|'fleet'|'fpga-image'|'host-reservation'|'image'|'import-image-task'|'import-snapshot-task'|'instance'|'instance-event-window'|'internet-gateway'|'ipam'|'ipam-pool'|'ipam-scope'|'ipv4pool-ec2'|'ipv6pool-ec2'|'key-pair'|'launch-template'|'local-gateway'|'local-gateway-route-table'|'local-gateway-virtual-interface'|'local-gateway-virtual-interface-group'|'local-gateway-route-table-vpc-association'|'local-gateway-route-table-virtual-interface-group-association'|'natgateway'|'network-acl'|'network-interface'|'network-insights-analysis'|'network-insights-path'|'network-insights-access-scope'|'network-insights-access-scope-analysis'|'placement-group'|'prefix-list'|'replace-root-volume-task'|'reserved-instances'|'route-table'|'security-group'|'security-group-rule'|'snapshot'|'spot-fleet-request'|'spot-instances-request'|'subnet'|'subnet-cidr-reservation'|'traffic-mirror-filter'|'traffic-mirror-session'|'traffic-mirror-target'|'transit-gateway'|'transit-gateway-attachment'|'transit-gateway-connect-peer'|'transit-gateway-multicast-domain'|'transit-gateway-route-table'|'volume'|'vpc'|'vpc-endpoint'|'vpc-endpoint-service'|'vpc-peering-connection'|'vpn-connection'|'vpn-gateway'|'vpc-flow-log',
            'Tags': [
                {
                    'Key': 'string',
                    'Value': 'string'
                },
            ]
        },
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing an entire list of SubnetId strings here:

```
           SubnetIds=[
                f"{subs['SubnetId']}",
            ],
```

> but I'm having some difficulty filtering the subnets to a single ID

You have a Python list of subnet ID strings. If you want just one item from the list, and you don't care which one, then just reference the first item in the list like you would any other Python list:

```
           SubnetIds=[
                subs['SubnetId'][0],
            ],
```